# Hidden Wifi jamming 5Ghz network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, repeater, interference

I recently moved to a new flat, including a new router supporting the dual band AC standard. The flat has really thick walls (reinforced with steel) so I need to put a repeater in the middle. The repeater does also support the AC standard.

And here is the problem: The **connection of the repeater is often lost**, as shown in the figure [Dropout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKVje.png).

I have already figured out that there is a "hidden (German = 'versteckt') jammer" nearby (flat above, below, or even my own) which is constantly turning on with relatively high power [JammerOn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJG8p.png)
and then switches off again. The transmitted power is really high. Almost like the power of my own router.
I will ask my - most probably unaware - neighbours what this could be. Yet, before asking them, I'm really curious what device could have such a behaviour. Switching constantly on and off, being a hidden network, being in the 5GHz range, having a really high power...

Has anyone experienced something similar? What kind of device could this be?

Comment: Have you tried changing your channels, the other network is 802.11a should be easy to avoid it.

Comment: Might it be [DFS (Dynamic Frequency Selection)](https://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/what-is-dynamic-frequency-selection-dfs) kicking in? Do you live in an area where there is possible radar interference?

Comment: I went to the lowest band possible (36) in Germany with a bandwidth of 20MHz.